# LEFT OUTER JOIN loses original userID

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, heroku, pg

Stepping up my PostgreSQL knowledge. Here's a working query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM associates a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ip b 
         ON a.userID = b.userID AND b.iPAddress = '124.xxx.xxx.xxx' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN browser c 
         ON a.userID = c.userID AND c.userAgent = 'Mozilla / whatever Gecko' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN location d 
         ON a.userID = d.userID AND d.country = 'US' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN session e 
         ON a.userID = e.userID AND e.lastAction >= now() - interval '24 hours' 
WHERE a.extensionID = 'xxxxx' 
LIMIT 1
```

Running this, assuming that all conditions are met, returns a nice hash which starts with `{'userid' => 12345, ... }` which I may want to use later (for example, if a session has expired, I'll need it to make a new one)

However, in case of any mismatch - for example - if the calling user's IP is changed - will result in the same hash but with lost data and more importantly, the hash will start with `{'userid' => nil}`

Said userID is obviously being used to match other tables, so why is it lost and more importantly, how to preserve it?

It makes sense, sort of: if there is a mismatch, nothing was "selected." Is there a way to preserve the original `a.userID` somehow?

I should mention I'm using Heroku's PostgreSQL [via pg gem](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wondering if may be picking up user id from another table (b.userID, c.userId, ...). Try selecting explicitly and changing name.

```
SELECT a.userID As MainUserId, * FROM associates a ...
```

So in the "*" All Fields, you have not one but five things which are called userId. You have a.userId, b.userId, c.userId, d.userId, and e.userId. So when you refer to userId it's ambiguous as to which one it refers to. If it's a.userId then you are right, it should never be blank. If one of the other, it could be blank because missing form the left join.

To make sure you're referring to the a.userId that you want, select it explicitly so you can reference it with no ambiguity. IN the sample code I put, I select it in addition to "everything" and name it explicitly so you can be sure that you're referring to the a.userId that is "reliable".

Answer (score 3):

Never ever use a * in production code, it's error prone. Column userid exists in all tables, but which one do you need? Just mention the columns you really need and use aliases when needed.

Comment: I've changed the first part to SELECT a.userID and then switched something else so that it does not match and I've received the return I want both times. I think if I list all of the things I actually NEED there, I'm golden. However, do you mind explaining a little bit why it is lost in the scenario I originally described?

Comment: It's not lost, you're code is just picking the wrong (empty) userID. Because of the *, you're not in control of the result, it depends for example on the query plan. And a query plan might change over time...

Comment: @FrankHeikens Er, what? If column identification is ambiguous due to use of an unqualified name with multiple possible matches you should get an error at parse time. Can you show a demo of what you're talking about? I'm wondering if there's some behaviour I've missed...

Comment: @CraigRinger: The error is made in the application code, it just picks the first/last/random column with the name userID. I've this issue in PHP-code. It's not a PostgreSQL/database problem.

Comment: @FrankHeikens ah, ok... that makes a *lot* more sense. It's also not surprising, especially in PHP, Rails+ActiveRecord, etc.